# OOP Observer Pattern: call notifyListener from outside of the subject

Tags: oop, design-patterns, observer-pattern

Is it ok for an Observer object to call `notifyListeners()` on an observable after changing some of its fields? What disadvantages could arise? Usually it's the subjects' responsibility to notify listeners of changes.

I frequently come across the following problem when wrapping model classes in an observable / subject e.g. to make them accessible in UI.

Should my subject notify its listeners whenever any field of the model object is changed or should I provide some kind of method `setModel()` that takes a new model object as an argument and only then notifies all listeners?

For example:

```
class MyData {
  String myString;
  int myInt;
}

class MyDataObservable {
  private MyData data;

  // constructor

  void setString(String string) {
    data.myString = string;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void setInt(int num) {
    data.myInt = num; 
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void notifyListeners() {...}

  void addListener(Observer o) {...}
}
```

I don't like that my subject basically mirrors all the properties of my model .. which is pretty ugly.

```
class MyDataObservable {
  private MyData data;

  // constructor

  void setData(MyData data) {
    this.data = data; 
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void notifyListeners() {...}

  void addListener(Observer o) {...}
}
```

The downside of this approach is that I have to build a new copy of my data class everytime anything changes, even if it's just a bool flag on my model class.

So my idea was to allow for observers to notify other listeners when they changed something with e.g. an `update` function.

Are there other, more elegant alternatives?

**EDIT**

At the moment, making my data class an observable is not an option because I'm using a framework that provides an observable mechanism that can also hold business logic. For that reason I want to decouple my data class and the logic / observable.

Comment: Do you need to have a separate `MyData` class at all?  What is it used for/ why does it exist? Why couldn't you use the observable class for that?

Comment: You say "observer" in comments, but your code says "Observable".  Those are very different things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case I would use inheritance rather than composition: `MyData` *is-a* `Observable` rather than `Observable` *has-a* `MyData`.

```
class Observable {
    Collection<Listener> listeners

    void addListener(Listener l) {...}
    void notifyListeners() {...}
}
```

```
class MyData extends Observable {
    String myString;
    int myInt;

    void setString(String string) {
        this.myString = string;
        notifyListeners();
    }

    void setInt(int num) {
        this.myInt = num; 
        notifyListeners();
    }
}
```